# Python questions multiple print lines ran as one line

Tags: python-3.6

Modify the following four (4) lines of code so that the output looks like:

> one, two, three, four

without removing any of the lines and only by adding `s` named argument.

```
print("one")
print("two")
print("three")
print("four")
```

I'm currently in school and this is an introduction to programming. It's 
online so all I really have is the book as a resource. If I'm not mistaken 
an `s` named argument is a string, isn't it? If anyone could help me out with this I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: have you read the Python docs for `print()` ?

Answer (score 0):

from documentation of [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

> Print objects to the text stream file, separated by sep and followed
>   by end. sep, end, file and flush, if present, must be given as keyword
>   arguments.

As you can see default keyword argument for end statement is `\n` hence it is always printing your string from new line but if you just override argument with `,` as shown in below code you will get your desire output.

```
print("one", end=", ")
print("two", end=", ")
print("three", end=", ")
print("four")
```

Output:

```
one, two, three, four
```